# How I can get the download URL of the latest version of Cura from it's website with powersell?

Tags: powershell, url, match, innerhtml, invoke-webrequest

I want to find download URL for the latest version of Cura right now it is (https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/releases/download/5.2.1/Ultimaker-Cura-5.2.1-win64.exe)
and I have written
`(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://ultimaker.com/software/ultimaker-cura").innerHTML -match "(https*.exe)"`
I tried it with .innerHTML or usebasicparsing or Invoke-Restmethod and I could not find it, can someone help me to find it?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the [release API from GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/releases#get-the-latest-release) to find out the latest release of the software.

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://api.github.com/repos/Ultimaker/Cura/releases/latest"
$windowsRelease = $response.assets | Where-Object { $_.name -match "win64" }
```

Please note that I am applying a `Where-Object` here to filter out only `win64`, because a release can contain binary for different platforms.

Then you can use `browser_download_url` property to get the download url which you can use it along side with `Invoke-WebRequest` to download it

```
# download the file
Invoke-WebRequest $windowsRelease.browser_download_url -OutFile "CuraLatest.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and response , how I can find a list of software that I can use the release API from GitHub for them? I mean for which Software can I use release API from GitHub ??

Answer (score 0):

Good day

When I try to download files from Powershell I use this:

```
$source = "https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/releases/download/5.2.1/Ultimaker-Cura-5.2.1-win64.exe"
$destination = "your download folder path"

#Using Webclient
$wc = [System.Net.WebClient]::new()
$wc.DownloadFile($source,$destination)
```

It's a simple way to use .Net to download files